# Find the values of $a,b \in \Bbb R$ (if exists) such that $-5 \le \frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3} \le 4$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Find the values of $a,b \in \Bbb R$ (if exists) such that $$-5 \le \frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3} \le 4$$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$

**My try:**
I noticed that  $x^2+2x+3 > 0$, so i can divide the inequality in 2 parts:

$-5(x^2+2x+3)\le x^2+ax+b $ $\space$ $\land$ $\space$ $4(x^2+2x+3) \ge x^2+ax+b$

After that i tried to manipulate the discriminant of both inequalities (both are quadratic equations) but i found nothing.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you mean that the inequalities should hold for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, i edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ be such that the inequalities hold. Then clearing denominators as you did yields the inequalities
$$6x^2+(a+10)x+(b+15)\geq0,$$
$$3x^2+(8-a)x+(12-b)\geq0,$$
for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. This means both polynomials in $x$ have nonpositive discriminants, i.e. that
$$(a+10)^2-24(b+15)\leq0,$$
$$(8-a)^2-12(12-b)\leq0.$$
Isolating $b$ from both inequalities yields
$$\frac{(a+10)^2}{24}-15\leq b\leq 12-\frac{(8-a)^2}{12}.$$
Moreover, a bit of algebra shows that for $a$ we then have
$$3a^2-12a-532\leq0.$$
By the quadratic formula this is equivalent to
$$|a-2|\leq4\sqrt{\tfrac{34}{3}}.$$
Can you finish from here?

---

For completeness, a nice and grainy plot of the solution set in the $(a,b)$-plane:

[image]

Comment: I exactly did that, but i don't know how to proceed with the discriminants.

Comment: I have added a few more steps, but I have left the end of the proof for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $$x^2+2x+3=(x+1)^2+2\ge2$$